# Can a ListTile be customized to accommodate Title, SubTitle, and another Text line/s?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was looking at a way to add additional lines in a ListTile other than the Title and SubTitle. Has anyone done it Or share how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

```
           Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: profile.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.png'),
                title: Text(profile[index].firstName + ' ' + profile[index].lastName),
                subtitle: Text('This is my speciality'),
                *****************
                **# Want to add another line her after the subtitle**
                *****************
                trailing: Text('$ 50'),
                visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                dense: true,
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtitle text wrap with `column` as follows:

```
ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset('assets/images/profile.png'),
                title: Text(profile[index].firstName + ' ' + profile[index].lastName),
               
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("test text"),
                    Text("test text")
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: Text('$ 50'),
                visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                dense: true,
                isThreeLine: tru
              ),
```

Image with multiple `subTitle`

[image]

Comment: Oh, That easy!!! I am a fool.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use a column for each of them .....

for example

```
                 ListTile(
                    leading: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('leading Line 1'),
                        Text('leading Line 2'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    title: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('title Line 1'),
                        Text('title Line 2'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('subtitle Line 1'),
                        Text('subtitle Line 2'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    
                  ),
```